# Mongoose query on referenced item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Basically I have a schema similar to this one

```
User_A {
    a_array: [{
       b: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User_B' }
    }]
}
User_B {
    b_name:String
}
```

What I need to do is to count how many distinct `User_As` have a specific `b` inside the a_array. I do not need to populate `b` so I thought I could query the `User_A` schema in this way to filter and find only the users who have that `b`

```
User_A.find({'a_array.b': my_user_b._id})
    .exec(function (err, result) {
    })
```

Provided that the `a_array.b` element is the `_id` of the referenced item before populating it. 
But I cannot have it working, always return an empty array even though I'm sure the `my_user_b._id` is correct.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: I tried and it works as expected. What is strange is that you get null, `find` should return at least an empty array.

Comment: @L.Meyer you are right actually I was using `findOne`, if I do use `find` I get an empty array. But it should not be empty, don't understand why

Comment: You confirm that you have records in your database ?

Comment: Yep, if I query `find({})` it returns me everything. You say anyway the syntax is correct and should be working? If that's so I will try to spot the error elsewhere, I thought I was in the query syntax

Comment: You could use `populate('a_array.b')` function to replace the references with the "real" objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `'a_array.b'`. Because `a_array` is an array, you cannot get the desired results like that. Try this.

```
User_A.find({
    a_array: {$elemMatch: {b: my_user_b._id}}
}, function (err, result) {

});
```

This should get you all the **User_A** records where `a_array.b` is `my_user_b._id`.